# Colour in the legend does not match colour in the plot (ggplot2 v 3.4.0)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have tried to search the answers to questions similar to mine, however I have not yet been able to come across a reliable answer so asking separately.

My dataframe named Vedo_Project2_CD38CD127 looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to create a boxplot of the variables in this specific order: PD1posCD8pos, TIGITposCD8pos, CD38posCD8pos. I have specified this order in the ggplot2 boxplot and it shows up correct in the graph itself (correct order and correct colouring). My issue lies in the legend which does not show the exact colours that I have specified, even though the ordering of the variable names in the legend is correct. For example, I have specified PD1posCD8pos to be "black", and it shows up as black in the boxplot, but in the legend PD1posCD8pos (now labelled as PD1+CD8+ for clarity) shows up as blue. How can I fix this so that the legend colours correspond to the order I have specified?

I am thinking that because CD38posCD8pos comes first alphabetically and since it is blue, the legend is forcing it to go first. Oddly enough, the previous version of ggplot2 re-ordered the legend automatically, so it is only this version that is giving me issues.

Please see my code below:

```
#colour vector
cols<- c("PD1posCD8pos"="black","TIGITposCD8pos"="red","CD38posCD8pos"="blue")

#plot
pw<- ggplot(Vedo_Project2_CD38CD127, aes(variable,value,fill=variable)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill="white",width=0.5,position = position_dodge(0.1)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y",stackdir = "center",dotsize = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(labels=c("PD1+CD8+","TIGIT+CD8+","CD38+CD8+"),values=cols) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("PD1posCD8pos","TIGITposCD8pos","CD38posCD8pos"))+
  labs(x="Sample",y="Frequency of PD1+/TIGIT+/CD38+ (% of CD8+ T cells)",fill="Legend")

pw
```

Please see the graph output that I am getting below:

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I would guess that the issue is simply that the wrong labels are assigned in the legend. You could check that by removing the labels from `scale_fill_manual` and to make sure that the right labels are assigned you could use a named vector as you did for the colors.

Comment: That is my guess as well. As general advice, if you set the `labels` in a scale, you should also set `breaks`. Otherwise you might be in for surprises like his.